# When is the earliest large prime gap also the latest large prime gap?

Tags: prime-gaps

Suppose one finds the earliest prime gap of at least a certain size $g$, so that $p_{n+1}-p_n=g$ and $n$ is the smallest index for which the gap is as big as $g$.

Now consider the *relative* size of the gap: $\dfrac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{p_n}$

When will $n$ be the largest index for which the relative size is that big?

Is the set of all values of $n$ for which that happens infinite?

Is the set of all values of $n$ for which that does not happen infinite?

(For example, this happens when $p_n=3$ and when $p_n = 113$.)

Comment: your relative size goes to zero. For sufficiently large $p,$ there is a prime $q$ with $p < q < p + p^{21/40}$

Comment: @WillJagy : That is of course what I would expect; otherwise this question would not have occurred to me.